# Titanium Android - Navigate records in SQLITE database

Tags: android, sqlite, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am just trying to work out how to navigate between records in an sqlite database using simple 'forward' and 'back' buttons.

I can acces the database and display the records - I do this by creating a tableview of the records then if you click on a record it brings up more details about it. I then just want buttons on this page to navigate through the database.

I am not sure what code needs to be applied to the buttons.

This is the code for the window.

```
// create var for the currentWindow
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var id = currentWin.id;


function photoGalleryDidClose(item) {
photoView.image = item.media;
}


var db = Titanium.Database.open('photos');

var sql = db.execute('SELECT * FROM photos where id=?', currentWin.id);

var recordID = sql.fieldByName('id');
var title = sql.fieldByName('title');
var location = sql.fieldByName('location');
var photographer = sql.fieldByName('photographer');
var equipment = sql.fieldByName('equipment');
var caption = sql.fieldByName('caption');
var notes = sql.fieldByName('notes');
var date = sql.fieldByName('date');
var imageUrl = sql.fieldByName('imageUrl');


//Labels to display catalogue details

var labelrecordID = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Record ID:',
    font:{fontSize:18},
    top:30,
    left: 10,
    height: 25,
    width:'auto'
})
currentWin.add(labelrecordID);

var labelrecordID1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'  '+ recordID +'',
    font:{fontSize:18},
    color:'black',
    borderRadius: 2,
    top:30,
    left: 150,
    height: 25,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    width:'300'
})
currentWin.add(labelrecordID1);


var labelTitle = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Title:',
    font:{fontSize:18},
    top:70,
    left: 10,
    height: 25,
    width:'auto'
})
currentWin.add(labelTitle);

var labelTitle1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'  '+ title +'',
    font:{fontSize:18},
    color:'black',
    borderRadius: 2,
    top:70,
    left: 150,
    height: 25,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    width:'300'
})
currentWin.add(labelTitle1);

//
//I CUT OUT A LOT OF THE CODE HERE AS IT IS JUST THE SAME AS ABOVE...
//

// create a view to add the label and photo
    var photoContainerView = Ti.UI.createView({
        top: 310,
        left: 10,
        height: 230,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL
    });

    var photoLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'Photo:',
        left: 0,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        font:{fontSize:18}      
    });

    photoContainerView.add(photoLabel);

    var photoView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image: imageUrl,
        top: 0,
        left: 125,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1
    });

    photoContainerView.add(photoView);
    currentWin.add(photoContainerView);


// create navigation buttons 
//
var button_previous = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Previous',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#464646',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    bottom: 20,
    left:10,
    width: 100,
    height: 60
});

currentWin.add(button_previous);

var button_next = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Next',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#464646',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    bottom: 20,
    right:10,
    width: 100,
    height: 60
});

currentWin.add(button_next);
```

I just want to add the event listeners to the button so I can go back/forward through the records in the database but I am unsure where to begin and what code needs to be utilised.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

JC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the click listener to refresh the table with new data, store your current place in the table and page through it like this:

```
var currentPage = 0;
var pageSize = 25;
button_next.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    currentPage++;
    // Load the data
    var sql = db.execute('SELECT * FROM photos where id>? LIMIT ?', currentPage * pageSize, pageSize);

    .... Your code to convert this statement to actual rows ....

    table.setData(yourUpdatedRowDataArray);
});
```

The previous button would work the same way except opposite.

Comment: Thanks for that - With a bit of tweaking works great! Thanks again